# How does swift handle deterministic finalization?

Tags: garbage-collection, finalizer, swift

I am coming from a C# background; as I understand it Swift have automatic memory management like C# does.

An issue in C# that requires the use of “programming patterns” is the timely releasing of resources, as the garbage collector runs at an undefined time, and hence cannot be used to close files, release network connection etc.   (Hence IDisposable and the “using” keyword)

How is this dealt with when programming in Swift?

Comment: C# is a garbage collected language, Swift has ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). That's something completely different.
Read about ARC, it works the same as in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

[Swift seems to use](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_50) there same memory management model like Objective-C with [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) enabled.

That means there is no garbage collector. Instead ARC uses reference counting with compiler inserted increment and decrement operations when (strong) references are being set.

The absence of a (threaded) collector means finalization is deterministic in Swift. Objects are deallocated when the last reference goes out of scope.

Comment: Do you know how this copes with object that are referenced from many threads?

Comment: @IanRingrose Threads do not really change the behavior of reference counting—except that the case where the counter goes to zero and the object is deallocated must be detected atomically. That's the case with ARC and works as expected even for weak references. Actually `retain` and `release` were thread safe at least since Cheetah (10.0).

Answer (score 0):

Swift have the ARC enabled same as Objective-C. You can find the reference from apple documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_50

Apart from swift's default handing mentioned by **NikolaiRuhe**, You can use the `deinit()` methods to force deallocation of objects. You can use this method to remove `observers` if you have implemented any.